# File upload images written details hidden but after downloading images it's showing

Tags: file-upload, salesforce

I have uploaded one passport image on conveyance record but when uploaded , the text that is written on image not visible but when downloading that image it's visible for me.

What can be the issue pls provide solution for this as soon as possible.
Like from where we can fix it.. Is there any visibility text off or any other reason.

please check and let me know.
Thank you.

I want to make passport image that i uploaded , it is how showing text of image after downloading
I can also able to see directly on record on salesforce.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.